# what method can be used to test the correlation between multiple ratios and their cumulative correlation to a single binary value?

Tags: regression, logistic, correlation

Let's say I have a certain number of rows, the first 3 columns of which are ratios, the last 1 is binary

These ratios interact with each other in various ways, but all contribute in some manner to a given binary result of 1 or 0. I know that spearman analysis focuses on two variables that have a linear relationship. Being that these ratios do not typically fall into a linear relationship, I don't think that will work. Any advice in what type of analysis to look into would be much appreciated.

Comment: A typical first step if you have three continuous predictors and a binary outcome is logistic regression. Have you considered logistic regression? If so, why did you exclude it? If the problem is highly nonlinear and therefore not a good candidate for logisitc regression, have you considerede a regression tree?

Comment: I guess I had mentally painted myself into a corner, as I was previously looking at a different set of data which worked well with a spearman analysis. Thank you for the insight. I will dive into that as well.